# Capybara tests using headless chromium not reading React code

Tags: reactjs, rspec, capybara, chromium, vite

**Problem**

When running e2e tests with Capybara in my Rails/React app, whenever the javascript uses React, it has trouble executing the code. `<div id="root"></div>` remains empty while the code renders properly locally and in docker. I've duplicated this running the capybara tests locally as well. What is odd is that if I add a `document.getElementById("root").innerText = "Foo bar"` it runs the javascript and either doesn't know how to execute the `ReactDOM.render` bit or just doesn't. When running tests against Stimulus code, it renders properly. For funsies, I downgraded to react 16 but had the same issue.

**Background:**

We use Vite js to bundle the javascript which I don't *think* is related but definitely could be. The app runs in an alpine docker environment but I can reproduce it locally so I don't think its specific environment related. Rails routes are empty endpoints that serves an empty html page with a #root div for React to hydrate and route accordingly. We're not using the `react-rails` gem. In the output of the html page, the assets are all pointing at the correct js files and the code does exist in those files.

**Code**

The main runtime code for capybara tests. I've included the code for the small react snippet I tested with the capybara test and the output of the `print page.html`.

`app/javascript/entrypoints/test.jsx`

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

// If this is uncommented, this line runs correctly but is not
// replaced by the "Hello World" in the `render` method
// document.getElementById("root").innerText = "Foo bar"

// This never gets run or is run incorrectly
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>Hello World</div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

`test.html.haml` (yes, I know haml is awful)

```
!!!
%html{lang: :en}
  %head
    = vite_client_tag
    = vite_react_refresh_tag
    = vite_javascript_tag "test.jsx"

  %body
    #root
```

`react_test_spec.rb`

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Testing react", type: :feature, js: true do
  describe "just checking", :with_csrf do
    before { visit test_home_path }
    subject { page }

    it "renders react" do
      print page.html
      expect(page).to have_content "Hello World"
    end
  end
end
```

`print page.html output`

```
<html lang="en"><head>
<script src="/vite-test/assets/test.92ee76c9.js" crossorigin="anonymous" type="module"></script><link rel="modulepreload" href="/vite-test/assets/jsx-dev-runtime.ddafb254.js" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body></html>
```

Config/setup code. Package versions, capybara/vite configuration, and etc.

`package.json`

```
    // react related packages
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "6",

    // vite related packages
    "stimulus-vite-helpers": "^3.0.0",
    "vite": "^2.9.1",
    "vite-plugin-ruby": "^3.0.9",
    "vite-plugin-stimulus-hmr": "^3.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.3.2",

    // babel related packages
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.17.12",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.17.10",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
```

`capybara.rb`

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome_headless do |app|
  options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
  options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
  options.add_argument("--window-size=1400,1400")

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, capabilities: [options])
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome_headless
```

`vite.config.ts`

```
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  plugins: [RubyPlugin(), react(), StimulusHMR()],
})
```

`vite.json`

```
{
  "all": {
    "sourceCodeDir": "app/javascript",
    "watchAdditionalPaths": []
  },
  "development": {
    "autoBuild": true,
    "publicOutputDir": "vite-dev",
    "port": 3036
  },
  "test": {
    "autoBuild": true,
    "publicOutputDir": "vite-test",
    "port": 3037
  }
}
```

`some packages in Dockerfile.development`. Also duplicated this issue locally using `chromedriver`

```
RUN apk add \
  build-base \
  chromium \
  chromium-chromedriver \
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS assets are likely built differently in dev and test modes - and this sounds like you have a JS bug which is preventing the hydration. Add a pause to  your test, run it in non-headless mode and look at the developer console for JS/network errors

Comment: Ended up finding `jsxDevRuntime.exports.jsxDEV is not a function` as the primary culprit and followed the solution laid out here to resolve. https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/5803#discussioncomment-1772907 hopefully helps someone out in the future